# Update field value fails

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL DB.

I have a cars table, by describing this table `describe cars`, I see the "`flag`" field of this table has type `tinyint(1)`.

I tried to update the value of "`flag`" field for all records in this table by executing the following command:

```
UPDATE TABLE cars SET flag=0;
```

But It fails, the **error** message is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near UPDATE TABLE cars SET flag=0
```

Why it fails? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE cars SET flag=0;
```

... the TABLE keyword is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE cars SET flag=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `TABLE` in there.

Try simply:

```
UPDATE cars SET flag=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

TABLE - is a reserved MySQL word.

```
UPDATE cars SET flag=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
UPDATE cars SET flag=0;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

delete `TABLE` keyword:

```
UPDATE `cars` SET `flag` = 0;
```